# React component in Astro cannot use the window object

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, preact, astrojs

I'm Using preact in my Astro project. Which works fine until I added `window

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Now I know that Astro does SSR but in this case its a React component icw `client:load`

So, in index.astro I have

```
  <Counter count={count} client:load>
        <h1>Hello, Preact 1!</h1>
  </Counter>
```

Counter is my React component:

```
export default function Counter({ children, count }) {
    const href = window.location.href;

    return (
        <>
            ...
        </>
   );
}
```

How can I fix this in my React component?

Comment: `useEffect()` should fix that if I understand this well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`client:load`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#clientload) still renders the initial view on the server, before hydrating it on the client.

[`client:only`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#clientonly) skips HTML server-rendering.

```
  <Counter count={count} client:only>
        <h1>Hello, Preact 1!</h1>
  </Counter>
```

Comment: This seems to solve the `window` error. In my case I had to do `client:only="preact"`. However, what this seems to break is `slots`. The Counter component has a console error: debug.js:333 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a child. Encountered an object with the keys

Comment: Probably the same issue as [https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/2265](https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/2265)

Comment: You can also stick with `client:load` but use `import.meta.env.SSR` to guard against accessing `window`, e.g. `const href = import.meta.env.SSR ? '' : window.location.href` if you’re happy with the link not having an address until the component hydrates.